# Need suggestions for a "TableLayout backed by adapter"-like View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-tablelayout, android-adapterview

I want a 7x4 table backed by an adapter that never scrolls, but rather will fit to take up its available space, sizing each cell in a uniform way. I want it backed by an adapter because it has built-in functionality for taking care of data set changes and recycling views. Here's a few things I've considered:

- Extending `AbsListView` and implementing it myself
- Extending `TableLayout` and giving it fields to pass in an adapter

Both seem cumbersome. I was wondering if people could see the light at the end of the tunnel, or know of any 3rd party libraries that already have what I'm seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GridView.

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/yourgridview"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:columnWidth="78dp"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:stackFromBottom="false" />
```

Then use java to set the adapter to the GridView.
Hope I helped.

Comment: That's what I'm using now. The problem is that `GridView` will scroll its content if it can't fit everything on the screen. I want it to fit on the screen without scrolling, resizing the children views if necessary.

Comment: Then you have to get the screen width and height, set the column width and item height as a % of the screen overall size. To get screen dimensions :
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

Comment: I may end up having to do that, but it'd be based off the parent `ViewGroup` since it doesn't it doesn't take up the whole screen.

Comment: Then use `GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.yourgridview); int width = gv.getWidth(); int height = gv.getHeight();` to get the GridView's size.

Comment: The size of the `GridView` isn't the problem. The problem is that once that size is exceeded, it will become scrollable.

Comment: `android:overScrollMode="never"`